# authentification method doesn't workj

Tags: java, sql

I try to create authentication method but it return always false its never enter in my If condition this is my code :

```
public boolean Authentification(String user, String password){

boolean result=false;
try {

conn=con.Connect();

stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet  rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from login  where user ='"+user+"' AND password='"+password+"'"); 
System.out.println(rs);
if ( rs.next()) {
result=true;
System.out.println("ici");
}
stmt.close();

conn.close();


}  catch (SQLException e) { 
e.printStackTrace();
}
return result;


}
```

Comment: I hope this will **never** make it into production... -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code, I guess the statement always returns nothing. Heaps of things to comment on though: Use *prepared statements*, don't store passwords in *clear text*, adhere to Java / SQL *naming conventions* (e.g. capitalisation).

Comment: it clearly says that your sql query did not return any results. Did you try to run exact same query using sql editor directly?

Comment: ok i will try thank you

Comment: I found problem my request use key word user i change it for userA it's work